# wamp windows .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess

This is the text inside my .htaccess file which is located in the root of my local windows server which is c:\wamp\www and so is my index.php file.

I have also enable rewrite_module from the apache tray menu.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php var_dump($url); ?> // not working.
```

Comment: Not working as it displays nothing? If you g to `index.php?url=test` does it display anything?

Comment: It dose not show anything. still it's an error

Comment: What does the error say?